# Tomcat JNDI Connection with MS SqlServer 2008 R2 issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, tomcat, jndi

I'm not able to solve the problem, 'cause NO ERROR is shown!!!
no exception is thrown, no error in log file... NOTHING! it only does nothing!

context.xml:

```
<Resource   name="jdbc/XXX"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="50"
    maxIdle="50"
    maxWait="20000"
    username="XX"
    password="XX"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1433;databaseName=XXX"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="1800"
/>
```

web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>SQLSERVER Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/XXX</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

import.java:

```
    try {           
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            log.info("0");
        dsSqlServer = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/XXX"); <---OK
            log.info("1");
            connSqlServer = dsSqlServer.getConnection(); <---THIS DOES NOTHING, "2" IS NEVER SHOWN IN LOG FILE!!!!!!
            log.info("2");
    ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.fatal("SQLSERVER: Impossibile connettersi al database: " + e);
    }
```

env. info:

Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
JVM Version: 1.6.0_29-b11
JVM Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
OS Name: Windows 7
OS Version: 6.1
OS Architecture: x86

please help me, I'm in trouble...

I've just notice that when I reload the App, in the logs\tomcat7-stderr log file, appears:

> 28-ott-2011 16.09.22 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
>   INFO: Reloading Context with name [/prev] has started 28-ott-2011 16.09.22 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   GRAVE: The web application [/prev] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. 28-ott-2011 16.09.22 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload INFO: Reloading
>   Context with name [/prev] is completed

what the hell is that?!?

Comment: TROVATO!

I went back to JVM version 1.6.0_24-b07 previously installed and everything is working!